# Kendo MVC Grid inside Kendo TabStrip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tabstrip

I have Kendo Tabstrip control place in a partial view and inside that tabstrip I have Kendo Grid.

```
         @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                .Name("tabstrip1")
                .Items(ts =>
                        {
                        ts.Add()
                        .Text("Tab Strip 1")
                        .Content(@<text>
                            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<testproject.Class.DiscussionBoard>()
                                .Name("kendogrid1")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                    {
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedBy).Title("Created By");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.Subject).Title("Subject");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.CommentsDescription).Title("Comments/Description");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.ModifiedOn).Title("Modified On ");
                                    })
                        .NoRecords("No Recod Exists!!")
                            )
                        </text>);
                        })
        )
```

When I run this I get this error 
[image: Error When Kendo MVC Grid is used inside kendo TabStrip]

I tried searching over the net but didn't find much about this problem

ASP MVC 5 Project

Help is always appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `GridBuilder.ToHtmlString()`:

```
.Content(Html.Kendo().Grid<testproject.Class.DiscussionBoard>()
    .Name("kendogrid1")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedBy).Title("Created By");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Subject).Title("Subject");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CommentsDescription).Title("Comments/Description");
        columns.Bound(p => p.ModifiedOn).Title("Modified On ");
    })
    .NoRecords("No Recod Exists!!")
    .ToHtmlString()
)
```

Comment: Thanks Man :) Finally I can go ahead with other work